How to set CreatedBy and setLastModifiedBy fields automaticaly within MongoDB
i currently have this issue while working on a Spring Boot project. i have a project entity that have this fields (CreatedBy and setLastModifiedBy), using the MongoDB EnableMongoAuditing annotation i was able to populate the Date fields. These two fields will reference the user that either created or modified the entity. currently i have the following implementation:
public Project create(Project project) {
    
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName()).orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException());
  
    getByName(project.getName()).ifPresent(existing -> {
      throw new ProjectAlreadyExistsException(existing.getName());
    });

    // refactor
    project.setActive(true);
    project.setCreatedBy(user.getId());
    project.setLastModifiedBy(user.getId());

    return projectRepository.save(project);
  }

As you can see the fields are set manually inside the service, which seems a bit odd and not like a good practice for me.
can this be done in another way?

Could you try extending the AuditorAware interface
import org.springframework.data.domain.AuditorAware;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Optional;

@Component
public class DatabaseAudtiting implements AuditorAware<String> {

    @Override
    public Optional<String> getCurrentAuditor() {

            User user = userRepository.findByUsername(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName()).orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException());


        if (user!= null) {
            userId= user.getId();
        }
        return Optional.of(userId);
    }
}

Ps: You can use your existing logic to fetch the user from db, as it validates that the Authentication Principal exists in your db. After that you just get the Id of your user (String or your data type) And Spring will automatically populate it any time you are using @CreatedBy and @LastModifiedBy.

this works for my use case, thank you for the fast reply. so as i understand the getCurrentAuditor method will get called whenever a CreatedBy or LastModifiedBy fields need to be created or modified (in case of LastModifiedBy).

Yes, that's correct
